# How to cross off the structure in chemfig

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I do not know how to cross off the structure in chemfig. It should look like on the picture [image: cross_off]

Thanks!

Here is my sample code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}


\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=1pt}


\renewcommand{\printatom}[1]{\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\schemestart[0,3,thick]
\scriptsize\chemfig{*6(-=-(-[,0.65]?-[:50,1.2]O-[:-12,1.3]-[:25]-[:-130,1.3]-[:165]O-[:195]?)=-=-)}
\arrow{
->[\footnotesize \textit{n}-BuLi, B(OMe)$_3$, KHF$_2$(aq)]  
[\vspace{5cm}\footnotesize THF, -78$^\circ$C to rt]}
\scriptsize\chemfig{*6(-=-(-(=[:90]O)-[:-30,1.1]BF_3K)=-=-)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could load `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}` and then say `\schemestart A \arrow(--[cross out,draw=red]) B \schemestop`

Comment: @chemist A chemistry comment. Normally, 'reaction doesn't proceed' is shown by putting a cross either over the arrow or just after it, rather than over the structure itself.

Comment: @JosephWright which then would be the arrow type `-/>` :)

Comment: @cgnieder Yes, in the various drawing packages there is often a special 'does not go' arrow for exactly this purpose :-)

Comment: I completely agree with you that this is not a "scientific way" to show that reaction doesn't go, but it more visually stressed out. Initially, I used this arrow type -/>

Comment: but it is barely seen in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer: you can load the Tikz library `shapes.misc` and simply say

```
\schemestart A \arrow(--[cross out,draw=red]) B \schemestop
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}


\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=1pt}
\renewcommand{\printatom}[1]{\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}

\schemestart[0,3,thick]
  \scriptsize
  \chemfig{*6(-=-(-[,0.65]?-[:50,1.2]O-[:-12,1.3]-[:25]-[:-130,1.3]-[:165]O-[:195]?)=-=-)}
  \arrow(--[cross out,draw=red]){%
    ->[\footnotesize \textit{n}-BuLi, B(OMe)$_3$, KHF$_2$(aq)]%
      [\footnotesize THF, -78$^\circ$C to rt]}
  \scriptsize
  \chemfig{*6(-=-(-(=[:90]O)-[:-30,1.1]BF_3K)=-=-)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am not sure if you red my yesterday's comment regarding my problem using this type of arrow -/>; so if I want to cross off the arrow in my reaction scheme not the product, what command I need to write?. I tried to insert same command right after \chemfig hoping that it will cross off the arrow, but it gives me an error message. Could you please help me with that? P.S. Do I need to make this request as a new question?

Comment: @chemist no I had not read it. If you want to notify someone in a comment you need to write his name with an @ before it in the comment. The owner of a post will always be notified, though. Regarding the problem with the `-/>` type arrow. I'm not sure what you want exactly. Do you want to have larger or thicker strokes?

Comment: both : and thicker and larger in red color otherwise the strokes are barely seen. Thanks

Comment: You could try to define your own arrow type (`-x>`?) for this. Or maybe redefine the arrow type `-/>`.

Comment: @chemist if you have problems with it you can always post a new question :)

Comment: @cgnieder Any particluar reason why you didn't load the `mhchem` package and use `\ce{B(OMe)3}, \ce{KHF2(aq)` in the arrow text? Not a complaint just an observation ;>

Comment: @Leeser no reason. Probably because the code in the question didn't use it either. I would have used the [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package, anyway...