# How to cross off the structure with an anchor in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to cross of the structure after the arrow (with an anchor) but I get a mess. I've been told how to do that without the anchor. I was trying to move a "cross off" command to different places but with no luck. Here is my sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=1pt}

\renewcommand\printatom[1]{%
  \fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont
  \ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\schemestart[0,1.2,thick]
\chemfig{CH_2=CH-C(=[:90]O)-COH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){%
->[\footnotesize 1. NaH][2. \textbf{1}]%
}[,2,thick]
\chemfig{Ph-CH_2-CH-C(=[:90]O)-COH}
\schemestop



\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you're refering to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121084/5049? Besides that I have no idea what you're tried or what you're trying to do...

Comment: @cgnieder Yes, you are right, I am referring to tex.stackexchange.com/q/121084/5049, but in this case \arrow(--[cross out,draw=red])(.mid east--.mid west) doesn't work and \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)(--[cross out,draw=red]) doesn't work either.

Comment: Out of curiosity: the `\textbf{1}` looks like a number referring to a compound. You're not actually using `\textbf{1}` but a package like [`chemnum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemnum) or [`chemcompounds`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemcompounds), right?

Comment: @cgnieder As you noticed, I am a newbie in Latex and I used \textbf{1} to label my compound because it was the fastest way I could get this done using chemfig manual. Fortunately, I needed only one compound to be labeled in my thesis. I've never heard about chemnum or chemcompounds packages and I should dedicate more time to learn Latex.

Comment: Well, for a single label you of course don't need those packages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cgnieder's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121317/3954) to [How to cross off the structure in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121084/3954):

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=1pt}

\renewcommand\printatom[1]{%
  \fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\selectfont
  \ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\schemestart[0,1.2,thick]
\chemfig{CH_2=CH-C(=[:90]O)-COH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west[cross out,draw=red]){%
->[\footnotesize 1. NaH][2. \textbf{1}]%
}[,2,thick]
\chemfig{Ph-CH_2-CH-C(=[:90]O)-COH}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]